# Same code, missing qtintf70.dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Compiling some old code, my application will no longer run. Newly compiled exe-file won't start "because qtintf70.dll is missing from your computer".

Strange thing: an older exe file compiled from exact same code runs just fine. Both exe files tested on same system, but compiled on different Delphi installations (both Delphi 7 running on VirtualBox).

Googling, someone suggested "You have pulled in Clx somehow. Clx apps require the QT library. Look for units in your uses clauses that start with Q." but again: this is the exact same code. I've checked and can't find anything.

Suggestions?

Comment: [Conditional compiler directives](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)) (typically [versions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Versions)) may bring in unexpected code.

Comment: Like I said: exact same code. I've also found a few older backups just to check - same problem. For some reason, compiling on this Delphi installation will cause the problem described.

Comment: Wrong search paths could bring in different sets of files.

Comment: In your Delphi Lib directory, are the DCUs identical between your problem installation and the other one(s)?  Same for any other folder(s) on your project search paths?

Comment: There's no reason the DCUs should be different. Everything originates from the same source (this latest installation was done from a backup after a hard drive failure). I can't remember having updated anything. Any way to tell which component or unit is calling this exact DLL? Using a hex editor, I find a reference to qtintf70.dll in the compiled exe, but no other clues.

Comment: "No reason" doesn't mean that they aren't (different).  Obviously something *is* different, otherwise you wouldn't be asking the q. "but no other clues": what does the MAP file say?

Comment: Sorry, bad wording. There's obviously something different. I have no way of comparing the DCUs. Like I said, the originals are gone. I don't know what to look for in the map file, but it doesn't include any references to qtintf70.dll if that is what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In D7, the only source code units which reference qtintf70.dll are QForms.Pas and Qt.Pas.

So, what you need to do is to

1. Move all instances of these two files and their corresponding .DCU files to somewhere not on your project's search paths.  Use a utility like SwiftSearch to make sure you find all of them.
2. Do a full build of the project.

The build should grind to a halt somewhere with a complaint that the compiler can't find one or other of these units.  The source unit that is being compiled at the time is the one which contains a reference to one or other of them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Following your procedure, I ended up throwing out an old unit I can easily manage without. I'm still puzzled why this hasn't been an issue before, but right now I'm just glad I was able to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarle: It hasn't been an issue before because there is a copy of qtintf70.dll somewhere in the PATH or in the executable's folder. That's the only possible reason that one copy of the executable works and another copy of the compiled executable doesn't but fails because the DLL can't be found. If the issue was during compilation, and the error was about a missing .pas or .dcu file, it would be a different issue, but this is specifically about the DLL not being found.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This is an old shareware application with thousands of users. Never been an issue, and this DLL is certainly not distributed with the application. Searching through earlier exe files, no references to qtintf70.dll are found, and the program will run on systems without the DLL (I've just tested). The unit causing the problem had QDialogs in its uses clause. Changed it to Dialogs and everything is fine. Again, I have no idea why this hasn't been a problem before. Hopefully this can help someone else in the future.

Comment: @Jarle Thanks for that information. I recreated some of the standard libraries (like Math) with Q prefix (so QMath) in order to save some bytes. And then by mistake I put QDialogs in the units instead of Dialogs. But QDialogs isn't mine. The program worked the same so it was hard to find the bad unit.